# Como puedo crear una api xml?

Tags: nodejs, api, xml

Se que es algo obsoleto o poco usado, pero necesito crear una api de este tipo para hacer pruebas de simulación de un sistema que tiene una api de este tipo.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de API? ¿REST? ¿SOAP?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Rest

Comment: He encontrado un artículo en inglés que describe hacerlo: https://blog.logrocket.com/reading-writing-xml-node-js/. Tal vez te ayude para empezar. Más código sobre este es en https://github.com/briandesousa/node-xml-demo, pero también con explicaciones en inglés. Preguntando aquí en es.stackoverflow probablemente busques algo en español, espero que tener un enlace a https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-xml-bodyparser ayude.